# Loading all PHP files all the time or only when they needed in Custom Plugin Development

Tags: plugin-development

Should I include all my PHP files automatically or should I include a model or class when it is needed only?

I used to use MVC PHP framework on which I only load needed models, helpers etc. But in Wordpress, does it make any sense?

Auto-including all files makes life easier but is it bad practice?

Comment: any answer to this is going to be incredibly subjective and highly opinionated, as well as extremely dependent on the contents of the files, their purpose, and what they do. I did write an answer, but I regret this, the question you asked would make for a good discussion topic, and if you're looking for reassurance or a sign that there is a "correct" way to do this the the answer is no, and when there is an answer it's much much more specific than the wide scope you asked about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's neither good or bad practice, the only true answer is ***it depends***.

**A concrete one size fits all answer to this question is impossible, and the question itself is micro-optimising.**

- For example if you know with certainty you don't need to load a file then don't load it. If that file contained hooks then they won't be added.
- if your file contains a class then why are you asking, just use an autoloader, and it'll be auto-loaded the moment it's first used
- if your file contains functions then yes include it
- *most importantly, unless your file is a template file, loading it should do nothing and have no performance cost*. e.g. loading a file with a class definition should define the class and nothing more, it should not execute code or create objects.

As for the performance implications, unless you have a huge number of PHP files this has negligible impact. When I say huge I mean PHP files that are in the double or triple digits of MB. Even then, it's far more likely that database queries and HTTP calls have a greater impact on performance, and by orders of magnitude.

So unless you spot that performance is dropping due to disk activity, performance does not factor into this. And if it does, it's probably because you're not using a modern solid state drive on your server.